# Difference between a JSP attribute and a parameter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameters, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between getAttribute() and getParameter() in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/what-is-the-difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter-in-java)

What is the difference between a parameter and attribute when using JSP.

Answer (score 8):

Parameters are part of the original request (e.g. from the browser).  Attributes are purely server-side, and are used to pass data when forwarding from, e.g. servlet to JSP.