# How could I set a unique ID inside an attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with some list items coded like this:

```
<li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/1.jpg"
    data-url="content/media/images/1.jpg"
    data-thumbnail-overlay-color="#aa4080">
    <div>
        <p class="gallery1DecHeader">First description</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

My purpose is to use the [ColorFinder](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/color-finder/index.html) JavaScript inside the `data-thumbnail-overlay-color="";`. This JavaScript needs 2 unique id, `image` (the original image) and `color` (the prominent color found) as shown in this [example](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/color-finder/demo.html).
Since I need to use it to change my overlay color, how could I insert the `color` id into my `data-thumbnail-overlay-color="";` attribute? Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: So basically you want to insert a string inside the "data-thumbnail-overlay-color", right?

Comment: @briosheje I'm here because I don't know what's the right way since I'm a novice coder...but to use it I need to set that id "color" into my attribute, just to use the color finder JavaScript

Comment: I'm not getting the question, that's the problem. What's the output you're expecting? I'm looking at this ColorFinder, and apparently needs just the image ID. So what you basically want to do is give to it the image, retrieve it's "RGB" and parse that RGB inside the data-thumbnail-overlay-color?

Comment: @briosheje from the page of the Script "This snippet assumes you have an image element in your page whose id is image. It also assumes there is an element whose id is color and sets its background to the dominant color of the image."

Comment: @briosheje I can set the id `image` to my list item, but I need to set the id `color` to my attribute `data-thumbnail-overlay-color="";`

Comment: Of course it does, so? In your <li> I see some parameters, but I'm not sure you can use that function if the image is NOT in the DOM. Perhaps you can try by passing that as an Image object, but from what I'm seeing in github (https://github.com/pieroxy/color-finder/blob/master/src/colorfinder-1.1.js) the script is PRETENDING to receive a DOM image element, which may not be exactly the same as a generic image object. Is the image of the **data-url** printed somewhere inside your document?

Comment: After a rapid test, the script also accept a generic image object. I'm going to try to provide an answer, despite your question is absolutely unclear.

Comment: @briosheje I wish to find the most prominent color of my thumbnail image. The path of the image is set like this: `data-thumbnail-path` and I wish to have the most prominent color found by the Script inside the `data-thumbnail-overlay-color` attribute.

Comment: data-thumbnail-path is not a valid parameter, it should be data-thumbnailPath or something like that.

Comment: @briosheje the `data-thumbnail-path` is an attribute of another JavaScript I used

Comment: You seem to mix two different notions, *id* and *parameter*:

 - The term *id* applies to HTML elements with the `id` attribute set (they must be unique for a given page);
 - When you talk about a JavaScript program that accepts variable input values, then you should talk of these values as *parameters* of the program.

It would make your question clearer with the correct terms.

Comment: @geceo My first question was with "parameter" than another user edited to "attribute"...I searched and found here the answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743365/difference-between-parameters-and-attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how you are printing your `<li>` element.

First of all, your tags inside the `<li` are not valid, you should not use the "-" character inside a `data`, therefore I would suggest you to change your HTML to this:

```
<li data-thumbnailPath="https://www.bitblokes.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/crunchbang-linux-logo-150x150.png"
    data-url="https://www.bitblokes.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/crunchbang-linux-logo-150x150.png"
    data-thumbnailOverlayColor="">
    <div>
        <p class="gallery1DecHeader">First description</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Note: the image is a PLACEHOLDER in this html, change it to what you have in your own page.

That said, just to give you a tip, here is a little snippet to do something that will insert into the `data-thumbnailOverlayColor` the HEX of the RGB data of the image provided inside `data-thumbnailPath`:

Javascript:

First, we have to write a function to convert the RGB result to a valid HEX code.. And we're going to steal that here: [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

```
function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}
```

Second, we're going to loop through EACH `<li>` element of the DOM and we will create an **image object** from the **data-thumbnailPath**. From that image object, we will temporarely create an instance of ColorFinder, retrieve the Most prominent color and PARSE it inside the **data-thumbnailOverlayColor** :

```
var liIterator = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < liIterator.length; i++) {
 var img = new Image();
    img.src = liIterator[i].dataset.thumbnailPath;
    var rgb = new ColorFinder().getMostProminentColor(img);
    liIterator[i].setAttribute("data-thumbnailOverlayColor", rgbToHex(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b));
}
```

The output is the following [visual]:

[image]

And the HTML output is this:

[image]

The working fiddle can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/82bo2wtx/

EDIT:

I'm wrong about the tag elements, "-" is accepted, but the above example works too.

In order to give you less work to do, here is the fiddle working for YOUR specific case: you just have to copy the following in a script and include that in your document or, even easier, at the very **bottom of your document (just slightly before the `</body>`**, write this:

```
<script type="javascript">
var liIterator = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < liIterator.length; i++) {
 var img = new Image();
    img.src = liIterator[i].dataset["thumbnail-path"];
    var rgb = new ColorFinder().getMostProminentColor(img);
    liIterator[i].setAttribute("data-thumbnail-overlay-color", rgbToHex(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b));
}

function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82bo2wtx/1/

** ASSUMING YOU HAVE ALREADY INCLUDED THE COLORFINDER LIBRARY **

Comment: I'm not that kind of novice :)

Comment: No one ever said you are a novice here ;)

Comment: I said before :D. Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to set an attribute of an element, you can do it like this:

```
var color="color";
var li=document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]; // or another selector
li.setAttribute("data-thumbnail-overlay-color", color);
```