# PageContext's scope

Tags: jsp, scope, el

In my understanding the method `findAttribute(String)` of the class `PageContext` searches for findings in all scopes (Session, Request, Pagecontext..).

Is that really so?

I have a JSP with the following code

```
String foo = request.getParameter("foo"); %>
<%= pageContext.findAttribute("foo") %> -- <%= foo %> -- ${foo}
```

So in my understanding if I previously set the requests parameter `foo` to anything like `boo` and the session and pagecontext is clean, all 3 outputs would deliver `boo`.

But in my case only the output in the middle says `boo`. `<%= pageContext.findAttribute("foo") %>` and `${foo}` have no o

Comment: How exactly is "parameter" the same as "attribute"? They have different wording, right? Wouldn't that mean that they have a different meaning? In any way, put your mouse above the `[el]` tag which you've put below the question and click the *info* link in the popbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pageContext.findAttribute` will retrieve **attributes** which are different than **parameters**.

See [Difference between getAttribute() and getParameter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter) for more details.