# How i can set value of attribute in jsp action dynamically?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have action in my jsp page `<jsp:include page = <%=(String)request.getAttribute("page")%> />` the `page` is request parameter that i have set previously in my servlet. But when i try to access my jsp page i get.

```
<jsp:include page = <%=(String)request.getAttribute("page")%> />
```

How to set `page` correctly ?

Comment: May be in single/double quotes - "<jsp:include page = '<%=(String)request.getAttribute("page")%>' />"

Comment: @NinadPingale i guess it could be rather `<jsp:include page = "<%=(String)request.getAttribute("page")%>" />` like this

Comment: @Ninad Pingale It works with single quotes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to avoid Scriplet instead use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) and [Expression language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) that is easy to user and less error prone.

> the `page` is `request parameter` that i have set previously in my servlet.

Since as per you its `request parameter` then you can access it using JSTL and EL from parameter.

```
${param.page}
```

---

If its set a `request attribute` the access it a below:

```
${requestScope.page}
```

See [Difference between getAttribute() and getParameter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter)