# How can I retrieve an array put in session from a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have the following problem.

Into the **service()** method of a custom servlet that implement the **HttpServlet** interface I put an **array** of custom object into the **session**, in this way:

```
// The collection that have to be shown in a table inside the JSP view:
SalDettaglio[] salDettaglio = this.getSalDettaglioList();

HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
session.setAttribute("salDettaglio", salDettaglio);
```

Then I want to retrieve this array **salDettaglio** into my JSP page. So I am trying to do something like this:

```
<%@ page import="com.myproject.xmlns.EDILM.SalReport.SalDettaglio" %>
<!-- showSalwf.jsp -->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<%
    out.println("TEST SALWF");

    SalDettaglio[] salDettaglio = request.getParameter("salDettaglio");

%>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that an error occur on this line:

```
SalDettaglio[] salDettaglio = request.getParameter("salDettaglio");
```

The IDE say to me that:

> Incompatible types. Required:
>   com.myproject.xmlns.EDILM.SalReport.SalDettaglio[] Found:
>   java.lang.String

Why? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use like:

```
(SalDettaglio[]) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("salDettaglio");
```

OR You could directly use something like:

```
<h4>${salDettaglio}</h4> <!-- if its a string say for example -->
```

OR you could even print using core's out EL like:

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.salDettaglio}"/> <!-- which again would be useless as its an array -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You have stored the `object` in the `session`,But you are accessing it from the `request`

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
SalDettaglio[]= (SalDettaglio) session.getAttribute("salDettaglio");
```

Also you need to use [`request#getAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)). see [Difference between getAttribute() and getParameter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter).

on the otherhand you can use simple `EL` expressions to access the elements from the `request` and `session` scopes,

```
 ${sessionScope.salDettaglio}
```

As using scriptlets is considered to be bad practice over the decades . Have a look at [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can use EL, which is prefered in JSP.

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.salDettaglio}"/>
```

Or if the name value is HTML safe, you can use

```
${sessionScope.salDettaglio}
```

Make sure the JSP is allow access session.

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
```

To use core JSTL, make sure the following code is included.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```