# I can not get the value of a request parameter

Tags: java, servlets

I have Servlet which rotates me some value `http://localhost:666/sg/queue?q=21343434`

I want to get the value `q`

```
@WebServlet("/queue")
public class QueueServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private List<String> queue;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        queue = new ArrayList<String>();
        queue.add("12324543254235");
        out.print(queue.size());
        out.print(request.getAttribute("q").toString());
    }
}
```

but when I write `out.print(request.getAttribute("q").toString());` nothing is displayed

and when I write `out.print(request.getQueryString());` displayed `q=21343434`

but I need to get only the very value `q`

Comment: Use getParameter() instead, refer to below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter

Comment: oooo thanks. strange as I have not found this method

Answer (score 1):

Use request.getParameter() to get param of url, the getAttribute() is used to get data of posted request.