# request.setAttribute is not working with chain.doFilter

Tags: servlet-filters

I have two servlet `ReplayFilter` and `VideoReplayServlet`. From `ReplayFilter`, I am calling `VideoReplayServlet` using `chain.doFilter`. I am able to call `VideoReplayServlet` from `ReplayFilter` but I am not able to get userId variable from request object in `VideoReplayServlet`,  which I have already set in request object before calling `chain.doFilter`. You can find my code below -

In ReplayFilter -

```
   request.setAttribute("userId", userId);
   request.setAttribute("uname", "mari");
```

chain.doFilter(request, response);

In VideoReplayServlet -

```
  String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
  String user_Id = request.getParameter("userId");
```

In VideoReplayServlet replay, I am getting both uname and user_Id null.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please post your `web.xml` file along with the code for the two methods in each servlet.

Comment: Interesting difference between getAttribute and getParameter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that you are setting it as an attribute and expecting it as a parameter which is contradicting. 
Try the below code instead

```
request.getAttribute("userId", userId); //Note the getAttribute() instead of getParameter()
```