# Set Cookie in HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

is there any way to add cookie to HttpServletRequest

Please help me..

i have tried this. but its not working

```
   HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    String cookie =   request.getHeader(HttpHeader.AUTHORIZATION.asString());
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest().setRequest(request);
    String authCookie = String.format("%s=%s", session_id, cookie );
    ServletRequest clientRequest = httpRequest.getRequest();
     httpRequest.setCookies(authCookie );
```

Comment: You set cookies in response, not request.

Answer (score 7):

I sent cookies in response. This is how I did it:

```
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();//We need this path to set cookie's path.
Cookie [] cookies = request.getCookies();
Cookie cookieToProcess = null;
for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    //Search cookie you need.
    if ("you-cookie-name".equals(cookie.getName())  && "your-coocie-path".equals(cookie.getPath())) {
        cookieToProcess = cookie;
        break;
    }
}
if (cookieToProcess == null) {
    //No such cookie. 
    //Possibly user enters your site for the first time or they disabled cookies.
    //In this case we create a new cookie.
    String cookieName = "your-cookie-name";
    String cookieValue = "your-cookie-value";
    Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
    newCookie.setPath(contextPath);
    response.addCookie(newCookie);
} else {
    String cookieValue = cookieToProcess.getValue();//Retrieve value from the cookie.
}
```

If you want to redirect or forward your request to the next jsp, servlet, etc, add request attribute 
see [Difference between getAttribute() and getParameter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to create a custom request wrapper extending HttpServletRequestWrapper

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private List<Cookie> cookies;

    public CustomRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.cookies = Arrays.asList(request.getCookies());
    }

    @Override
    public Cookie[] getCookies() {
        return this.cookies.toArray(new Cookie[0]);
    }

    public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
        this.cookies.add(cookie);
    }
}
```

This way you can easily remove or add cookies to the *List* in the class, and the requests *getCookies()* method will return your modified list of cookies. Note, that despite cookies have a separate *getCookies()* method, they are just http headers in the end, so the *getHeaders()* method won't return your modified cookie list in the Cookie header. If you want *getHeaders()* to work, you have to override that method as well.

Comment: This won't work as is. `Arrays.asList(request.getCookies())` will return a fixed-size list so `this.cookies.add(cookie)` will fail with an `UnsupportedOperationException`. So use `this.cookies = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(request.getCookies()));` in the constructor instead.