# Getting null from request.getAttribute()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a .jsp file that sends data via the post method to a servlet, but when i try to access the data in the servlet via request.getAttribute(), it prints out "null"

my .jsp file looks like this:

```
            <form name="update" action="UpdateServlet" method="post"
            accept-charset="utf-8">
            <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="input_name"    id="input_name"><br>
            <label>Beschreibung:</label> <input type="text" name="input_beschreibung" id="input_beschreibung"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="input_id" id="input_id">
            <input type="submit" value="Okay">
            <button type="button" onclick="closeDialog()">Abbrechen</button>
            </form>
```

my servlet looks like this:

```
public class UpdateServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    System.out.println((String)request.getAttribute("input_id"));
    System.out.println((String)request.getAttribute("input_name"));
    System.out.println((String)request.getAttribute("input_beschreibung"));

    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("LoadServlet");  
    rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

part of web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>UpdateServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>wochenplaner.UpdateServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>UpdateServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/UpdateServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

i dont understand why the attributes of the request are empty.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `request.getAttribute("")` and `request.getParameter("")`. You need to use the latter:

```
public class UpdateServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    System.out.println(request.getParameter("input_id"));
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("input_name"));
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("input_beschreibung"));

    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("LoadServlet");  
    rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

See here for some further discussion:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5243833/1356423

Comment: Thank you, i feel so stupid.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
request.getParameter("input_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `request.getParameter()` not `request.getAttribute()`

[Difference between getAttribute() and getParameter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter)