# How to dynamically set JSP hidden value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP that uses an  tag with a hidden value to pass to the doGet in a servlet and so far this works well.  However, can I change the hidden value dynamically?  Currently it is

```
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="COMMAND1" />
```

but I want the COMMAND1 to be one of two commands.  I tried changing the line above to this;

```
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="<%=request.getParameter
  ("USE_COMMAND") %>" >
```

Then the doGet in the servlet calls the procedure below and I tried setting the command as shown here but it doesn't work. Can this be done?

```
private void processCommand(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
  response) throws Exception {

    ....

    // dynamically set hidden command for JSP form GET
    String useCommand = "COMMAND2";
    request.setAttribute("USE_COMMAND", useCommand);

    ....

   // send to JSP page (view)
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher
     ("/theJSPPage.jsp");
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `getAttribute()` method in your JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="<%=request.getAttribute("USE_COMMAND") %>" >
```

This post explains the difference: [Difference between getAttribute() and getParameter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter)

Comment: Thanks Michael.  That seems to have worked