# how passing HttpServletRequest argument works?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

```
@RequestMapping("/returnformv2")
public String serveletTest(HttpServletRequest request){        
    String firstname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lname");
    String fullname = lastname.concat(firstname);
    request.setAttribute("fullname", fullname);     
    return "helloworld";
}
```

Now if I retrieve from JSP, ${fullname} is lastname.concat(firstname).
Let me show some basic java code, say I call serveletTest("hello");

```
public String serveletTest(String myString){        
    System.out.println(myString);
    myString = myString.concat(world);
    return "bye world";
}
```

myString should be still "hello" right?

For me, getParameter() from HttpServletRequest makes sense but not request.setAttribute(). Could someone please explain how this works?

Comment: request.setAttribute("fullname", fullname);  sends the String object "fullname" to your jsp. If HttpServletRequest makes sense to you than request.setAttribute() should also make sense.

Comment: If you assign back to the `myString`, you will see the updated `myString`. Like `myString=myString.concat(world);`. Same applies to `fullName` scenario as well.

Comment: Please check in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter

Comment: `myString` will still be `hello` because strings are immutable.  `String.concat` does not alter a string, but returns a new string which is the result of concating strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for. X(
RequestDispatcher was doing all the magic...

According to javadoc,

> void javax.servlet.ServletRequest.setAttribute(String name, Object o)
>
> Stores an attribute in this request. Attributes are reset between
>   requests. This method is most often used in conjunction with
>   RequestDispatcher.

web.xml --> Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet and Set up URL mapping

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```