# How can we transfer json object from servlet to a jsp page and how to fetch that json data in jsp page?

Tags: java, json, jsp

The scenario is I want to transfer my json object from my servlet to a jsp page and fetch the datas from json and display in jsp page.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's great. But have you tried anything? Any research to solve it?

Comment: Look [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `getAttribute()` which is for server-side usage only. [You set an attribute in a servlet, and read it from a JSP. Can be used for any object, not just string.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5243798/2815219)

Once you have called your servlet, you can simply set an attribute with your JSON object and then you can forward this request to your jsp page

```
request.setAttribute("jsonObject", jsonObject);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/processor.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And in your JSP page, get that JSON object and use it:

```
<%
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) request.getAttribute("jsonObject");

    out.println(jo.get("somekey"));
    ...
%>
```